# Tried to Airdrop a specific video (.mp4) got the error 'Failed to save item. Save to iCloud Drive instead'

Tags: airdrop

I Airdrop tons of mp4 video files to my phone, but for some reason, I have one video file that fails to AirDrop.

I examined the Get Info window of each one that worked and of the one that didn't. Same approximate size, same file type, etc.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Edit: This happened when I exported from Premiere. Found [this thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/can-t-airdrop-premiere-project-exported-as-mp4-quot-failed-to-save-item-save-to-icloud-drive-instead/td-p/10644689/page/2) that had lots of ideas.

Comment: How is Premiere relevant here? Is the only video which doesn't work the only video exported from Premiere? Also, which of the ideas in the linked thread have you tried already?

Comment: SO told me to edit the question or ask a new one. Here is the new better question with answer - https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/420068/some-videos-seems-random-exported-from-premiere-cant-be-airdropped-to-iphone/420069#420069