# Some videos (seems random) exported from Premiere can't be Airdropped to iPhone

Tags: airdrop

Editing videos in Premiere, sometimes a certain video fails to Airdrop to an iPhone.

I examined the Get Info window of each video that worked and of the one that didn't. Same approximate size, same file type, same codex etc. Looked at the settings in Premiere seem similar.

Anyone know how to solve this?

Found this [thread](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/can-t-airdrop-premiere-project-exported-as-mp4-quot-failed-to-save-item-save-to-icloud-drive-instead/td-p/10644689/page/2) and tried a bunch of the suggestions.

Tried converting it to .mov in Quicktime failed.
Tried saving it as 4k in Quicktime failed.
Tried importing it to Photos (works) then Airdropping it. Failed.
Tried trimming it in Quicktime. Failed.
Tried uploading it to Dropbox then downloading it to Photos on the iPhone. Failed.

Answer (score 1):

Digging through the thread I linked in the question ([this one](https://community.adobe.com/t5/premiere-pro/can-t-airdrop-premiere-project-exported-as-mp4-quot-failed-to-save-item-save-to-icloud-drive-instead/td-p/10644689/page/2)) finally found steps that solve it for me.

**Sequence Settings**

- Pixel Aspect Ratio: Square Pixels
- Fields: No Fields (Progressive
  Scan)
- Display Format: 29.97 fps Drop-Frame Timecode

**Export Settings**

- Format: H.264
- Preset: Match Source - High Bitrate

Ensuring these settings are the same in every sequence makes it so all the videos exported are able to Airdrop to and play on iOS.